# How can I send more than 1 photo by telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

I want to send more than 1 photo to people from bot. So if I will write three time "bot.send_photo" it won`t be 1 message, so I want to send >1 photo in 1 message. How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean, but this might answer your question

```py
img = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"]

for i in img:   
    print(i)
    #bot.send_photo(chat_id, 'your URl or image path')
```

Comment: U are sending 3 photos in 3 different messages. I need to send 3 photos in one same message